# How is the modular multiplication matrix unitary in Shor's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, quantum-computing, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have been reading papers about the construction of this matrix in Shor's Algorithm all night. The behavior of the controlled modular multiplication matrix is described as

$$C U_{a^{2}}(|c\rangle|y\rangle)=|c\rangle\left|\left(a^{2^{i}}\right)^{c} y \bmod N\right\rangle$$
in [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0511.pdf)

It's described [similarly here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/in-the-shors-quantum-circuit-what-is-the-transformation-of-the-modular-operati)

The issue I have is this **does not seem** to be unitary, since $N<2^n$, we can get stuff like this:

$$C U_{a^{2}}(|c\rangle|0\rangle)=C U_{a^{2}}(|c\rangle|N\rangle)=|c\rangle\left| 0\right\rangle$$

I don't understand how modular multiplication can possible be inversible when we explicitly choose $N < 2^n$, and so there have to be values the mod to the same result.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/in-the-shors-quantum-circuit-what-is-the-transformation-of-the-modular-operati) you mention, the unitary $CU_{a^2}$ only works as a controlled modular exponentiation matrix for states $|c\rangle |y\rangle$ with y<N. Hence $|c\rangle |N\rangle$ should not necessarily map to $|c\rangle |0\rangle$ (and by your argument indeed it doesn't).

Comment: A more detailed descriptions of reversible modular multipliers: https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6614 (in particular, it says what to do with numbers exceeding $N$).

Comment: Thank you! I was really confused